# Sharing INSTALLDIR in InstallShield

Tags: installshield

Is it possible to share INSTALLDIR after installation?

Answer (score 0):

Care to elaborate? Do you mean windows file sharing, share the property value, share the folder location between applications?

You can write the `INSTALLDIR` property to the registry, and then access that from other applications, plugins, etc.

Comment: Sorry. I meant window file shareing. So that other computers on the network will be able to se the folder.